# Vim Plugin for centering text

Tags: vim

Some time ago I stumbled upon a vim plugin which centers the text you're editing.
It was posted on HN and featured in HNNewsletter, but I dont remember the name...

Is there somebody who recognizes the plugin?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably talking about [vimroom](https://github.com/mikewest/vimroom).

Comment: Well we're talking about two really different things! :-) But as I don't read "HNNewsletter", there is a high chance that you are the one who got the question right, +1

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was talking about. :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a plugin. The ex command [`:center`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3acenter) does exactly that,
centering to a specified width, which defaults to your [`textwidth`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27textwidth%27) option
or 80, if the latter is set to zero.

```
======================================================================
When that your flock, assembled by the bell,
Encircled you to hear with reverence
Your exposition on the holy text
Than now to see you here an iron man,
Cheering a rout of rebels with your drum,
Turning the word to sword and life to death.
======================================================================
```

```
:%ce 70
```

```
======================================================================
             When that your flock, assembled by the bell,
                 Encircled you to hear with reverence
                   Your exposition on the holy text
                Than now to see you here an iron man,
              Cheering a rout of rebels with your drum,
             Turning the word to sword and life to death.
======================================================================
```